# Swift - Strange Sprite behaviour using accelerometer

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, accelerometer

I'm a beginner with swift and have my first game nearly complete except for one really annoying issue. I have a sprite that flies around the screen, the accelerometer determines the X position and touching the screen moves the sprite up the screen. This works 95% of the time just the way I intend, but every now and then the accelerometer just stops working for 30 second to a minute - I can't find any pattern to this and it's driving me crazy - does anyone have any suggestion ? Partial code below

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{



var destX:CGFloat  = 0.0
var Blast = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Blast")
var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

var Texture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Bat")
var Texture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BatJet")


 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

// Scene Setup Physics

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsBody!.friction = 0
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(-0.0, -0.8)


// Set Up Player

     TheBat.texture = (Texture1)
     TheBat.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y:      self.frame.size.height/2)
    TheBat.setScale(0.25)
    TheBat.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: TheBat.size)
    TheBat.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    TheBat.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    TheBat.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    TheBat.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bat
    TheBat.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ship
    TheBat.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge | PhysicsCategory.Ship

    self.addChild(TheBat)

// Determine Player X Position

    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1      motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueu e(), withHandler: {
 (accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in

 let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration

 self.destX = (CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.75) + (self.destX * 0.25)
})


override func didSimulatePhysics() {

// Set velocity based on x-axis acceleration

TheBat.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: destX * 600.0, dy:     TheBat.physicsBody!.velocity.dy)}
```

Comment: I've changed (CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.75) + (self.destX * 0.25) to  (CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.7) + (self.destX * 0.3) and also set the accelerator updates to stop at the game over screen and reset destX to 0.0 which appears to have worked.